# Angular2 - getting error as : `EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on MyComponent`

Tags: angular

when i trying to import a directive from other file, i am getting the error as `EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on MyComponent` - how to solve this?

here is my code:

app.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {MyComponent} from "./app.my-component"

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
        <h1>Hellow World</h1>
        <span>Here is your component:</span>
        <my-component></my-component>
    `,
    directives: [MyComponent]
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

app.mycomponent.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({

    selector : 'my-component',

    template : `<h2>This is from My component</h2>`

});

export class MyComponent { };
```

But i am getting error as : `No Directive annotation found on MyComponent` how to solve this?

Comment: `import {MyComponent} from "./app.my-component"` is this correctly exporting your component?

Comment: Maybe you need to make sure that the path is relative to your app root's folder, not from where you created the component. something like `import {MyComponent} from "../app.my-component"` or just `import {MyComponent} from "./app.my-component"`

Comment: @john Both files are within same folder only

Comment: @3gwebtrain, have you tried our suggestions ?

Comment: @micronyks - yes. but not working

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should remove `;` after component closing `Component` directive parenthesis.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({

selector : 'my-component',

template : `<h2>This is from My component</h2>`

})
export class MyComponent { };
```

Comment: Is your file name 'app.mycomponent.ts' or 'app-mycomponent.ts'?

Comment: my file name is `app.my-component.ts` -

Comment: now try with full static path and tell us for which path it works correctly?

Comment: @micronyks -  here is my app https://www.dropbox.com/s/xdahp4e8g07dvaz/demo.zip?dl=0 download and have a look

Comment: @3gwebtrain, I have created a `plunkr` code, and it's working, a ";" was the problem, you can check by putting it and looking at `console`.
http://plnkr.co/edit/GLdViZfwAoWRx99g6k7E?p=preview

Comment: Maybe, you did not transpile typescript into js?

Comment: i do. can you please download my file and see?

Comment: Yes I am looking at it, can you please look into plunker as well?

Comment: It's `});` maan. You should set it to `})`. Remove `;` It was on your code you provided. You didn't remove it as I said. It's on `app.my-component.ts` file.

Comment: yes. this is my bad. i have removed around other than the function. but it should not be the case to break the app. !

Comment: It is the case breaking the app, I checked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106206/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-turdaliev-nursultan).

Comment: Thanks! I had this same problem and was trying to solve it for at least an hour!

Comment: sorry but i have the same problem, anyone had found a solution? and most of all, isn't an error really strange and too much generic? is there a way to debug it? for example my problem is on @injectable() directive.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to make a relative path instead. It depends of where the component you want to import is located relative to the script you are importing the component in. Something like

`import {MyComponent} from "../app.my-component"`

or

`import {MyComponent} from "./app.my-component"`.

It would help if you posted your folder structure as well.

Comment: if i use `import {MyComponent} from "../app.my-component";` then i am getting error as : systemjs throws error as : `http://localhost:3001/app.my-component 404 (Not Found)` in case if i use  your second suggesion i am getting error as `No Directive annotation found on MyComponent`

Comment: Sorry I could not be of any help. Have look at the code from this blog post: http://blog.edenmsg.com/angular2-typescript-gulp-and-expressjs/ . Maybe you will find the source to your problems from it. I used that post as a reference when creating my first angular 2 application.

Answer (score 0):

oke, i am also still 'learning' on this, but i got the same message as you did.
i think i solved it...

found my answer here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html

add this to your app.mycomponent.ts:

```
import {Directive} from 'angular2/core';
```

and add the directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[MyComponent]'
})
```

hope this helps you a bit.

Again, NOT sure if this is the right way...

Comment: euh, so after deleting this solution from my code, cause i was not happy with it as the 'end solution', i thought it would crash again... but it didnt... very very weird. Cache problem maybe?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a problem with the export of a particular class, and the importing of that class in other components.

But this error was not shown explicitly, instead it manifested as the exception in `EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation...` in the console.

In order to get this error explicitly:

1. Stop the local server
2. Re-run `npm start` (assuming the Angular quickstart setup)

Any current errors that were previously hidden will show up immediately.