# No Directive annotation found on CoursesComponent

Tags: angular, typescript

I am following this tutorial. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-CD_5YhJTA

But I keep getting this error:

```
EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on CoursesComponent
```

my app.components.ts looks like this

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CoursesComponent} from './courses.component';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>Hello Angular 2</h1><courses></courses>',
    directives: [CoursesComponent]
})



export class AppComponent { }
```

my courses.components.ts looks like this

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';  

@Component({
    selector:'courses'//css selector
    template: '<h2>Courses</h2>'
})


export class CoursesComponent{ }
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",    
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install" 
  },  
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",
    "systemjs": "0.19.22",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^1.7.5"
  }
}
```

How do I solve this issue ?

Comment: `component` doesn't support `directive` attribute. What is your `angular2` version? They removed `directives` attribute  either on rc.3 or 5..

Comment: @choz in the package.json it shows version 1.0.0

Comment: Can you post your `package.json`?

Comment: @choz I updated the question.

Comment: Are `app.component.ts` and `courses.components.ts` in the same directory level? Can you also try to add a comma after `selector:'courses'` to make sure it's not a type error? Also check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35981553/angular2-getting-error-as-exception-no-directive-annotation-found-on-mycom) since it might help. But you know, you don't have to use `angular2` beta version anymore.. They now have the stable version at `2.2.4`. That tutorial you followed is using outdated version of angular2.

Comment: @choz I tried adding the comma, it didn't make a difference. Yes they are both in the app folder and I tried upgrading the angular version but still nothing worked. I tried following the thread but none of the solutions helped.

Comment: You stated your file name as `courses.components.ts`.. But, you're importing it like `from './courses.component';`. Try to update it to `./courses.components`. (*Notice the missing `s`*)

Comment: @choz the renaming didn't help. So i tried to reinstall the new angular and ran npm install then npm start and it worked ! Thank you SO much

Answer (score 0):

In your courses.components.ts  put ";" after class declaration  like this

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';  

@Component({
    selector:'courses'//css selector
    template: '<h2>Courses</h2>'
})


export class CoursesComponent{ };
```

Hope it will solve Your problem . if problem comes again then check your angular 2 version after that run npm install in your cmd

Comment: Why do you think this will be an answer while all of the components end without a semicolon in the documentation? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: Then Try to use npm install -g angular-cli@latest and then run npm install. Hope it will solve Your problem .

Answer (score 0):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, CoursesComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Comment: OP is using `angular2: 2.0.0-beta.7` :/

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear 
there are 3 kinds of directive

Components—directives with a template.
Structural directives—change the DOM layout by adding and removing DOM elements.
Attribute directives—change the appearance or behavior of an element.

you wrote a component with @Component annotation 
But you are declaring it in directives array 
In order to use your component just declare it in delcarations array in app.module.ts. the component will be accesible across the app

Read angular documentation for more details on directives and @directive annotation for creating attribute and structural directive 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html